# Prompting for user input (like Perl's $inp=<>) in Raku

Tags: raku

How do we do Perl's  '

`$inp=<>;`

to prompt user a single line, in Raku ?

As `lines();` keep on prompting a user input so not work identically

Please help clarify

Comment: Hi. :) Do either of our answers get anywhere close to what you're asking? Please consider commenting on what we're missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

> to prompt user a single line, in Raku ?

The [prompt](https://docs.raku.org/routine/prompt) function does this.

```
my $input = prompt;            # No message
my $name = prompt 'Name: ';    # Or with a message
```

Answer (score 6):

See [`get`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/get), which is an alias for `lines(1)`, or something pretty close to that.

It initially surprised me how hard it is to discover in Raku resources -- doc, design doc, chat logs, etc. But I guess `<>` and `line` are so overloaded that it's not that odd after all.

I've added [a comment about `get`'s (lack of) discoverability in the doc issues queue](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/3872#issuecomment-1030752692). It would be helpful to those working on the doc if you added another comment in the same issue saying where you'd looked to get (!) an answer to your Q.